# ListFragment: ArrayAdapter и OnBackPressed

Tags: android, массивы, android-fragment

Имеется 2 класса.

Первый класс:

```
public class List extends android.support.v4.app.ListFragment
{
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1, adapter2, adapter3;
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.test1));
    setListAdapter(adapter1);
    adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    if (getListAdapter() == adapter1) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.test2));
                setListAdapter(adapter2);
                adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
                break;
            case 1:
                break;
        }
    }
    else if (getListAdapter() == adapter2) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                adapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.test3));
                setListAdapter(adapter3);
                adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
                break;
            case 1:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Второй класс:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

При нажатии на пункт списка пользователю открывается второй список, где также можно нажать на пункт и перейти в третий список и т. д. Работает всё отлично, только необходимо реализовать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "Назад" приложение не закрывалось, а открывался предыдущий список.

Каким образом можно передать название ArrayAdapter'a (adapter1, adapter2, adapter3) в другой класс в метод onBackPressed, и возможно ли это?

P. S. Насколько мне известно, использование FragmentTrasaction здесь не подойдёт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно по разному. Например, в `onBackPressed` узнавать какой адаптер назначен списку и отталкиваясь от этого менять адаптер во фрагменте. Если же установлен первый адаптер, то только в этом случае вызывать `super.onBackPressed();`. Далее весь вопрос в том как организовать общение меж активити и фрагментом. Это так же можно сделать множеством способов. И гугл знает их все)

Навскидку:

1. Получить в активити ссылку на фрагмент через `FragmentManager`. Далее дёргать публичные методы фрагмента. Это не лучшая практика.
2. Использовать систему посылки сообщений. `LocalBroadCastManager`, `Handler` или сторонние библиотеки типа `Otto` или `EventBus`. Библиотеки предпочтительнее.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, правда возникает новый вопрос: какие ещё есть способы "общения" между фрагментом и activity (ответ на этот вопрос как раз искал в Гугле), а также почему библиотеки предпочтительнее?

Comment: @Win_D, ну, ещё можно совместить 1 способ с передачей меж ними интерфейсов... Но, в отличии от библиотек (кои, в основном, на `Handler` основаны) нужно много лишних действий совершать и учитывать кучу нюансов. Например, `LocalBroadCastManager` может очень странно себя вести) А библиотеки как раз созданы для решения задач обмена информацией меж сущностями, кои не должны по идее, иметь представления друг о друге.